# Hiding revmob banners when playing videos and certain screens

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, revmob

I have implemented revmob ads in my app. 
A movie player app.

The problem I have is that the banners still show when i play movies the app basiclly links to mp4 files that play in the stock iphone video player.

how do i tell xcode to hide ads when the player is active

I know i use the [RevMobAds hideBanner]; command i don't know where to put the code.

Comment: How do you start the video player?

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use the banner as a subclass of UIView:

```
RevMobAds *revmob = [[[RevMobAds alloc] initWithAppId:appID delagate:self]];
RevMobBannerView *bannerView = [revmob bannerView];
```

Then integrate this in you layout the same way you do with any UIView.
You can consult the [RevMob API docs](http://sdk.revmob.com/ios-api/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks M8 I will try this and let you know how i get on